# Xpath get distinct nodes using preceding-sibling

Tags: xpath, distinct, siblings

I need to get distinct values //name() withount distinct-values(//*/name())

I tried do like this, but its dosent work.

```
//*/name()[.!=//preceding-sibling::*]
```

How can i repair it?

Comment: Please could you provide a sample of your input and a clearer description of what you want to achieve?

Comment: distinct-values(//*/name())      i need to get the same results byt without this function

Comment: Yuliya, take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15812118/xpath-expressions) and see how much easier that question is to answer.

Comment: @MattH, i loked at that post, but i dont know how change my xpath(

Comment: That was to show you how to ask a question. I've asked you to include a sample of your input and output. I've also pointed you at an example of a well-asked question. How about you have a [read of this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) and then update your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **`XPath 1.0`**, to get the distinct values

For name attribute,

```
/*/*[not(@name = preceding::*/@name)]
```

For node name,

```
/*/*[not(name() = preceding::*/name())]
```

### My Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <friend1 name="abc"/>
    <friend2 name="def"/>
    <friend3 name="abc"/>
    <friend1 name="abcd"/>
    <friend5 name="abcd"/>
    <friend6 name="xyz"/>
    <friend8 name="789"/>
    <friend0 name="pqr"/>
    <friend9 name="lmn"/>
    <friend2 name="lmn"/>
    <friend5 name="123"/>
    <friend7 name="456"/>
    <friend12 name="789"/>
</root>
```