# Xpath expressions

Tags: xml, xpath

I am in need to get the value of `<mathcolor>` element for the element `<colorvalue>` has value 2. Please correct the Xpath expression given below:

**Xpath Expression tried:**

```
/colors/child::color/child::mathcolor[colorvalue='2']
```

**Sample XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<colors>
    <color>
        <mathcolor>#007dc5</mathcolor>
        <textcolor>C=100 M=40 Y=0 K=0</textcolor>
        <colorvalue>2</colorvalue>
    </color>
    <color>
        <mathcolor>#ed1b34</mathcolor>
        <textcolor>C=0 M=100 Y=85 K=0</textcolor>
        <colorvalue>3</colorvalue>
    </color>
</colors>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Almost, try that:

```
/colors/child::color[colorvalue='2']/child::mathcolor/text()
```

or simpler

```
/colors/color[colorvalue='2']/mathcolor/text()
```

Comment: The `child::` are superfluous, aren't they? I preferred your initial answer

Comment: Yes there are but I wanted to use the exact example siva2012 used in his question.

Comment: Might need a `/text()` on the end to get the *value*

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to target the actual element you want first with //mathcolor.  The rest is there to say that if you continued down the structure you would see a following sibling node named colorvalue with a text node = 2.

```
//mathcolor[./following-sibling::colorvalue[./text()='2']]
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation to your answer.

Comment: What if the order of the children of `color` is not defined? Maybe `//mathcolor[../colorvalue='2']/text()` would be more stable?

Comment: I like it, not sure I've seen a whole lot of occasions where the order of the child nodes change.